# Graphed data by R mismatch calculated data from Excel

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I have an experiment with 4 replicates. I used the following set of code to produce the attached graph. The total weed weight of each treatment is greater than the calculated total from excel. For example, the total weed biomass from Treatment `O4conv` is  about 249.76 kg/ha but the graphed data is about doubled. The same pattern applied to other treatment, too. Please see where I have made a mistake. Thank you.

Total weed biomass of 4 reps was calculated with

```
mutate(realmass=10*speciesmass/samplearea.m.2.)
```

in which the total biomass = [sum of individual weed's mass]*10 (to convert gram per meter sq to kg to ha).

Equivalent to (in the [excel data sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jb6gjznyw2q16mx/AADcNKiicqkoHxpFYIsaTgk9a?dl=0)), `kg.ha` = 10* (Sum of `ABUTHWt` to `UnknownmonocotWt`)/`samplearea.m.2`

Then the average, which I wanted to graph, was calculated with

```
summarize(avgrealmass=mean(realmass, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
```

in which I expected R to divide the `realmass` by 4 then graph the result.

```
weedweights<-weeds%>%
  select(-ends_with("No"))%>%
  gather(key=species, value=speciesmass, DIGSAWt:UnknownmonocotWt)%>%
  mutate(realmass=10*speciesmass/samplearea.m.2.)%>%
  group_by(Rot.Herb, species)%>%
  summarize(avgrealmass=mean(realmass, na.rm=TRUE))%>%
  filter(avgrealmass != "NaN")%>%
  arrange(-avgrealmass) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(species = gsub("Wt$", "", species))

ggplot(weedweights, aes(x=Rot.Herb, y=avgrealmass, fill=species))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+         scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","burlywood4","olivedrab","orange","chocolate","azure4","cornflowerblue","maroon","cyan","lightblue","blueviolet","darkgoldenrod","darkgrey","darkmagenta","dodgerblue","gold","darkslateblue","darksalmon","greenyellow","deeppink","brown1","cornsilk","orchid","black","pink2"),name="Species")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Weed biomass by treatment") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=16, face="bold", vjust=2)) +
  xlab("\n\nTreatment") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", vjust=4), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ylab("Total weed biomass (kg per ha)") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold", vjust=2))
```

Here is the data

```
 weedweights <- structure(list(Rot.Herb = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("A4conv", "A4low", "C2conv", 
    "C2low", "C3conv", "C3low", "C4conv", "C4low", "O3conv", "O3low", 
    "O4conv", "O4low", "S2conv", "S2low", "S3conv", "S3low", "S4conv", 
    "S4low"), class = "factor"), species = c("DIGSA", "SETFA", "SETLU", 
    "AMATA", "CHEAL", "PHYSU", "TAROF", "EPHHT", "SONAR", "MORAL", 
    "OXAST", "Unknownmonocot", "DIGSA", "SETFA", "SETLU", "AMATA", 
    "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "TAROF", "EPHHT", "SONAR", "Unknowndicot", 
    "Unknownmonocot", "SETFA", "AMATA", "SOLPT", "PHYSU", "TAROF", 
    "EPHHT", "MORAL", "SETFA", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "PHYSU", 
    "POLPY", "ABUTH", "TAROF", "EPHHT", "SONAR", "ASCSY", "SETFA", 
    "SETLU", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "PHYSU", "ABUTH", "TAROF", 
    "MORAL", "DIGSA", "SETFA", "SETLU", "ERBVI", "AMATA", "CHEAL", 
    "SOLPT", "PHYSU", "ABUTH", "TAROF", "MORAL", "Unknowndicot", 
    "Unknownmonocot", "DIGSA", "SETFA", "SETLU", "AMATA", "SOLPT", 
    "PHYSU", "ABUTH", "TAROF", "EPHHT", "SONAR", "MORAL", "OXAST", 
    "DIGSA", "SETFA", "SETLU", "ECHCG", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", 
    "PHYSU", "POLPY", "ABUTH", "TAROF", "EPHHT", "OXAST", "POLLA", 
    "SETFA", "SETLU", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "POLPY", "TAROF", 
    "POLAV", "PLAMA", "Unknownmonocot", "SETFA", "SETLU", "AMATA", 
    "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "PHYSU", "TAROF", "Unknownmonocot", "DIGSA", 
    "SETFA", "SETLU", "PANCA", "CYPES", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", 
    "PHYSU", "TAROF", "EPHHT", "CIRAR", "OXAST", "DIGSA", "SETFA", 
    "SETLU", "PANCA", "CYPES", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "PHYSU", 
    "TAROF", "EPHHT", "SONAR", "MORAL", "Unknownmonocot", "AMATA", 
    "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "PHYSU", "POLPY", "TAROF", "MORAL", "DIGSA", 
    "SETFA", "PANCA", "ECHCG", "ERBVI", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", 
    "PHYSU", "ABUTH", "TAROF", "MORAL", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", 
    "PHYSU", "ABUTH", "TAROF", "MORAL", "Unknowndicot", "SETFA", 
    "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "ABUTH", "TAROF", "EPHHT", "SETLU", 
    "ECHCG", "AMATA", "CHEAL", "SOLPT", "PHYSU", "ABUTH", "TAROF", 
    "EPHHT", "MORAL", "Unknowndicot", "DIGSA", "SETFA", "AMATA", 
    "CHEAL", "TAROF"), avgrealmass = c(6.25, 26.35, 58.35, 13.4666666666667, 
    17.1, 1.15, 28.75, 0.45, 0, 0.2, 1.2, 0, 6.425, 18.65, 6.63333333333333, 
    3.475, 6.11666666666667, 16.1, 41.9625, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0.0809410748974746, 
    0.237427153032592, 0.0917332182171379, 0.0647528599179797, 0.105223397366717, 
    0, 0.0539607165983164, 0.795920569825167, 5.7818907835096, 13.3822577163825, 
    1.62151953377941, 3.1099359666163, 0.388517159507878, 0.0539607165983164, 
    0.0845384560040291, 0.0701489315778114, 0.0539607165983164, 0.0215842866393266, 
    0.0539607165983164, 54.8240880638895, 0, 0.0269803582991582, 
    0.102525361536801, 0.0215842866393266, 0.0647528599179797, 0.0404705374487373, 
    0.0161882149794949, 0.485646449384848, 11.2103388733002, 86.4990287071012, 
    22.9333045542845, 13.9218648823656, 49.6798330815167, 0.0944312540470537, 
    0.661018778329376, 0.410101446147205, 0.399309302827542, 0, 1.18173969350313, 
    0.0161882149794949, 0.134901791495791, 1.24649255342111, 1.95877401251889, 
    0.00269803582991582, 0.364234837038636, 0.555795380962659, 0.356140729548888, 
    0.0350744657889057, 0.0944312540470537, 0.00809410748974746, 
    0.00539607165983164, 0, 1.42186488236564, 15.7794625512627, 0.584574429815095, 
    11.7094755018347, 1.75372328944528, 2.4552126052234, 0.50992877185409, 
    0.0863371465573063, 0.221238938053097, 9.53305993236924, 0.106572415281675, 
    0.117364558601338, 0.075545003237643, 1.40297863155623, 31.45, 
    14.0666666666667, 18.7375, 15.225, 22.3166666666667, 24.05, 8.775, 
    1.05, 0.4, 0, 8.55, 35.475, 31.4375, 35.4375, 15.4, 16.55, 7.15, 
    0, 105.05, 5.775, 0.8, 0.1, 37.85, 23.3375, 6.35, 97.4, 22.925, 
    138.2875, 8.26666666666667, 0.2, 16.25, 8.075, 28.9, 10.1, 1.05, 
    8.85, 34.6375, 59.425, 87.7, 4.45, 179.9875, 1.8, 34.45, 0, 0, 
    0.585473775091733, 0.0161882149794949, 0, 0, 0.113317504856464, 
    0.305777394057126, 0, 1.61342542628966, 1.62961364126916, 2.36887545866609, 
    7.94301748327218, 17.4832721778545, 30.8034750701489, 3.40761925318368, 
    0.627743003093748, 0.582775739261817, 1.46773149147421, 0.0575580977048708, 
    0.00899345276638607, 0.539607165983164, 0.364234837038636, 0.0431685732786531, 
    0, 0.407403410317289, 0.0229333045542845, 0, 0, 21.8540902223182, 
    43.1591301532484, 57.2172458450248, 0.793222533995251, 1.14396719188431, 
    0.215842866393266, 0.113317504856464, 0.0647528599179797, 0.0917332182171379, 
    0.453270019425858, 0.0431685732786531, 0.0485646449384848, 0.0161882149794949, 
    0.879559680552558, 0.00269803582991582, 0.0161882149794949, 0.0143895244262177, 
    0.0215842866393266, 0.075545003237643, 5.71983595942154, 34.9719404273689, 
    4.31685732786531, 0)), .Names = c("Rot.Herb", "species", "avgrealmass"
    ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -184L))
```

and here is the graph

[image: and here is the graph]

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in the data manipulation/calculation, not in ggplot.  If you sum up `avgrealmass` by `Rot.Herb` in R, e.g. `weedweights %>% group_by(Rot.Herb) %>% summarise(sum(avgrealmass))`, the results match the height of the bars in ggplot.  Note that the sum for `04conv` is ~462, so if it's supposed to be ~249 you have a miscalculation somewhere.

Comment: @aosmith Thank you. To get rid of some overcomplication, I remove the conversion of g/m2 to kg/ha. So the calculation of biomass is just mass/sampled area. I still can't figure out why the numbers are so different.